# Ubuntu giving error while installing in VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization

I downloaded Ubuntu ISO and burned the image on a CD. I created a new Linux hard-disk in VirtualBox and while VirtualBox is installing Ubuntu from that CD, it generates following error after some time:

**(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system**

Is the image not complete? I downloaded the entire thing. Can I supply the entire file-set through my hard-disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to burn a CD when using VirtualBox. You can boot your VM directly from an iso file. If this still doesn't work, make sure your image file isn't corrupted/truncated.

Comment: Even if the .iso is located on the hard drive?

Comment: Hopefully. http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#storage-cds

Comment: @Rohit - yes. Just point to the ISO file http://i.imgur.com/ahMWJ.png